# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach') with ajax method

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I have ajax funtion:

```
<div class="quiz-box"></div>



...



    const url = window.location.href

    const quizBox = document.getElementById('quiz-box')

    let data

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: `${url}data/`,
        success: function(response){
            // console.log(response)
            data = response.data
            data.forEach(el => {
                for (const [question, answers] of Object.entries(el)){
                    quizBox.innerHTML = `
                        <b>${question}</b>
                    `
                }
            });
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error)
        },
    })
```

Which gets data from django view.

Now this results in an error in console:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach') at Object.success at j**

**at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith]**

**at x**

**at XMLHttpRequest.b**

Why is this error occuring and how can I prevent this?

Comment: Is your data type an array? first check that

Comment: @PanktiShah how can i do that?

Comment: console.log(data) before  forEach

Comment: I get [{…}] and then a big dropdown section. Is that array?

Comment: yes that is an array

Comment: @PanktiShah so what should I do?

Comment: Can you tell me what you get typeof data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249382/discussion-between-kurac-and-pankti-shah).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the **optional chaining** (?.) operator to check if the variable is not null before accessing it.

**change  :**

```
data.forEach(el => {.....
```

**to :**

```
data?.forEach(el => {.....
```

and make sure to access `div` correctly you have to :

**change  :**

```
   <div class="quiz-box"></div>
```

**to :**

```
<div id="quiz-box"></div>
```

Comment: Now I get another error:
(index):202 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML')
What does that mean?

Comment: this error occurs when accessing the innerHTML property on a null value. in your example you are using  `getElementById` but providing a class name to it   not id  . I updated my answer